# formating tensorflowjs object detection executeAsync output to human reabale

Tags: object-detection, tensorflow.js

I'm wondering how to format the executeAsync tensorflow object detection executeAsync methods output so it look liks this:

[image]

My current output looks like this and is impossible to read just by browsing through:

[image]

I have been browsing through the coco-ssd.js, but for some reason it is written terribly.
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/coco-ssd
of course this needs to be beautified, but after that, there is almost not a single variable called by its name, its basically the all letters in the alphabet.

This is how I get my prediction (unformated):

```
async function asyncCall() {
  const modelUrl = 'http://192.168.0.14:8000/web_model_4/model.json';

  const img = document.getElementById('img');
  const imgTensor = tf.browser.fromPixels(img);
  const t4d = imgTensor.expandDims(0);

  const model = await tf.loadGraphModel(modelUrl).then(model => {
    predictions = model.executeAsync(t4d, ['detection_classes']).then(predictions=> { //, 'detection_classes', 'detection_scores'
      console.log('Predictions: ', predictions);
    })
  })
}
asyncCall();
```

Help is appreciated. I'm sure there are others having the problem training custom models with coco ssd.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are executing your own model and as a result need to format your output in a way that is human readable. If you were using the tfjs model coco-ssd (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/coco-ssd), you will get the formatting out of the box.
Regarding what you are calling `written terribly`, it is because of the minification of js.

Back to the original question: how to format the output ? Looking at what is printed in the console, we can see that it is a tensor. So if you want to print it, you will first need to download its data first:

```
predictions = model.executeAsync(t4d, ['detection_classes']).then(predictions=> { 
      const data = predictions.dataSync() // you can also use arraySync or their equivalents async methods
      console.log('Predictions: ', data);
    })
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is fantastic. I'm working with coco-ssd for about a week now, with the many versions of dependencies and the multiple tutorials on all kind of OS's, it was quite frustrating to get things to work. I knew that my problem was in understanding coco-ssd.js and it was frustrating, because I just couldnt read it, but print every single line out. It would be amazing for newbies, since this is such a interesting topic for people starting out to have a neatly commented version of coco-ssd.js (hope I didnt miss that).

Comment: Maybe I did not understand the entire coco-ssd paradigm yet, but my understanding is that you have to create your own model in order to detect your own objects. In my case chairs on a architectural plan layout. Anyway. So thank you again for your solution, in case I would want to add a string array: ['detection_classes', 'detection_boxes'] it gives me an error saying that "predictions.dataSync is not a function". I just copy pasted the part you have sent, times three and added a different string each time, which worked fine. That doesn't look so great, idea for imrovement?

Comment: Maybe that predictions is an array of tensor. If that's the case, you can get the first tensor with: `predictions[0].dataSync()`. The commented code is here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/coco-ssd/src

Comment: Can you actually have a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62574058/tensorflowjs-object-detection-coco-ssd-config-file-max-total-detections-explanat - it kind of is a follow up I guess.