# how to make sense of tensorflowjs object detection tensor output?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api, tensorflow.js

My motivation is to build a custom objection detection web application. I downloaded a `tf2` pretrained `SSD Resnet1010` model from [model zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md). My idea is if this implementation works, I will train the model with my own data. I ran `$saved_model_cli show --dir saved_model --tag_set serve --signature_def serving_default` to figure out input and output nodes.

```
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
  inputs['input_tensor'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_UINT8
      shape: (1, -1, -1, 3)
      name: serving_default_input_tensor:0
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
  outputs['detection_anchor_indices'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (1, 100)
      name: StatefulPartitionedCall:0
  outputs['detection_boxes'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (1, 100, 4)
      name: StatefulPartitionedCall:1
  outputs['detection_classes'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (1, 100)
      name: StatefulPartitionedCall:2
  outputs['detection_multiclass_scores'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (1, 100, 91)
      name: StatefulPartitionedCall:3
  outputs['detection_scores'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (1, 100)
      name: StatefulPartitionedCall:4
  outputs['num_detections'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (1)
      name: StatefulPartitionedCall:5
  outputs['raw_detection_boxes'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (1, 51150, 4)
      name: StatefulPartitionedCall:6
  outputs['raw_detection_scores'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (1, 51150, 91)
      name: StatefulPartitionedCall:7
Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

Then I converted the model to tensorflowjs model, by running

```
tensorflowjs_converter --input_format=tf_saved_model --output_node_names='detection_anchor_indices,detection_boxes,detection_classes,detection_multiclass_scores,detection_scores,num_detections,raw_detection_boxes,raw_detection_scores' --saved_model_tags=serve --output_format=tfjs_graph_model saved_model js_model
```

Here is my javascript code (this goes inside vue methods)

```
    loadTfModel: async function(){
        try {
            this.model = await tf.loadGraphModel(this.MODEL_URL);
        } catch(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }

   },
    predictImg: async function() {
        const imgData = document.getElementById('img');
        let tf_img = tf.browser.fromPixels(imgData);
        tf_img = tf_img.expandDims(0);
        const predictions = await this.model.executeAsync(tf_img);
        const data = []
        for (let i = 0; i < predictions.length; i++){
            data.push(predictions[i].dataSync());
        }
        console.log(data);
    }
```

The output looks like this:
[image: Screenshot]

My question is does these eight items in the array corresponds to eight defined output nodes? How to make sense of this data? and how to convert this into a human-readable format like the python one? 
**Update 1:**
I have tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62570047/2204131) and edited my predict method:

```
predictImg: async function() {
        const imgData = document.getElementById('img');
        let tf_img = tf.browser.fromPixels(imgData);
        tf_img = tf_img.expandDims(0);
        const predictions = await this.model.executeAsync(tf_img, ['detection_classes']).then(predictions => {
            const data = predictions.dataSync()
            console.log('Predictions: ', data);
        })

    }
```

I ended up getting, `"Error: The output 'detection_classes' is not found in the graph"`. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

There might probably a mistake in the output node specified in `this.model.executeAsync(tf_img, ['detection_classes'])`. Additionnally, there is no need to use `await` here `await this.model.executeAsync(tf_img, ['detection_classes'])`. Either `await` is used or `then` is used.

The other option to get the `detection_classes` is to index the array of output:

```
predictions[i].dataSync()[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you first need to check the `web_model/model.json` file and investigate the name of the outputs. Those are the ones you will need to use when filtering what to display (the following is my example file).

[image]